Leaking water out of pipe in basement floor.Sewage water when using water upstairs?
Tonight I came downstairs and the stubbed pipe in my basement was leaking sewer water out . If we flush a toilet or use drains it leaks. My basement is stubbed with just pipes and vents.

what is your question?

So, you have a clogged drain somewhere past the basement, causing sewage to back up into the basement rather than flow down the pipe as it should.
Get it cleaned out, whether DIY by renting an appropriate snake, or by calling a plumber, depending on your inclination.
